# Always Getting a "FALSE"

Tags: java, oop

I'm making a quiz program. First step, I'm taking the quiz questions and their correct answers from the teacher/ user. I have a child class named TrueFalseQuestion which takes the boolean model answer and the string question as a parameter. I've made an array of TrueFalseQuestion type and I'm stuck at this part where I run the code, insert a question and no matter whether the model answer I've inserted is true or false, it's always stored as false when I print it out. HELP? 
Here's this part of my code:

```
   System.out.println("How many true or false questions would you like to include in your quiz?");
    int l=s.nextInt();
    TrueFalseQuestion[] qu2= new TrueFalseQuestion[l];
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<l;x++){
        System.out.println("Please insert question "+(x+1)+":\n");
        String Q2=s.next();
        System.out.println("Please insert the correct answer");
        boolean A2=s.nextBoolean();
        qu2[x]=new TrueFalseQuestion(Q2,A2);
        System.out.println(qu2[x].GetCorrectAnswer());


}
```

EDIT: Here's the TrueFalseQuestion code

```
public class TrueFalseQuestion extends Question {
   private boolean CorrectB; 

   public TrueFalseQuestion(String qu, boolean b){
         super(qu); 
   } 
   @Override 
   public void GetQuestion() { 
         System.out.println(getMyText()+"\n Is this statement true or false?"); 
   } 
   @Override public String GetAnswer() { 
       System.out.println("Insert Answer: "); 
       boolean MyAnswer=s.nextBoolean(); 
       return Boolean.toString(MyAnswer); 
   }

   @Override public String CheckAnswer() { 
   return Boolean.toString(GetAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(Boolean.toString(GetCorrectAnswer(‌​))));
    } 
   /** * return the MyAnswer / /* * return the CorrectAnswer / public boolean GetCorrectAnswer() { return CorrectB; } /* * return the MyAnswer */ 

   }
```

Comment: Probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java   though you don't show the actual "compare answers" code.

Comment: have you use == instead of `.equals()`? That would be why.

Comment: We have to see your code for `TrueFalseQuestion`

Comment: No comparisons happen until this point in my code, I'm just directly printing what I have inserted in the previous step. I generally use .equals(), yes.

Comment: Um, you still haven't posted the `TrueFalseQuestion` code.

Comment: public class TrueFalseQuestion extends Question {
    private boolean CorrectB;
    public TrueFalseQuestion(String qu, boolean b){
        super(qu);
}


    Override
    public void GetQuestion() {
        System.out.println(getMyText()+"\n Is this statement true or false?");
    }

    Override
    public String GetAnswer() {
        System.out.println("Insert Answer: ");
        boolean MyAnswer=s.nextBoolean();
        return Boolean.toString(MyAnswer); 
           }

Comment: Override
    public String CheckAnswer() {
    return Boolean.toString(GetAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(Boolean.toString(GetCorrectAnswer())));
    }

    /**
     * return the MyAnswer
     */

    /**
     * return the CorrectAnswer
     */
    public boolean GetCorrectAnswer() {
        return CorrectB;
    }



    /**
     * return the MyAnswer
     */

    
}

Comment: Excuse my slow responses.@RealSkeptic

Comment: @dkatzel           Check this out. Really sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is your constructor:

```
public TrueFalseQuestion(String qu, boolean b){ 
    super(qu);
}
```

You don't set the field `CorrectB` so it defaults to its default value which in java is `false`

the fix is

```
public TrueFalseQuestion(String qu, boolean b){ 
    super(qu);
    CorrectB = b;
}
```

Comment: I can't thaaaaank you enough!!!! :')

Answer (score 0):

Problem is nextInt() leaves "\n" in the stream and when next() executes in
    String Q2=s.next();
It reads "\n" and doesn't gives you an opportunity to input Question.

Try this:

```
System.out.println("How many true or false questions would you like to include in your quiz?");
int l=Integer.parseInt(nextLine());
TrueFalseQuestion[] qu2= new TrueFalseQuestion[l];
int x;
for(x=0;x<l;x++){
    System.out.println("Please insert question "+(x+1)+":\n");
    String Q2=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please insert the correct answer");
    boolean A2=s.nextBoolean();
    qu2[x]=new TrueFalseQuestion(Q2,A2);
    System.out.println(qu2[x].GetCorrectAnswer());
}
```